# Host Web Api in self hosted NServiceBus

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nservicebus

I'm looking for how to use a self hosted NServiceBus, which starts and hosts Web Api. I can't seem to find any resources on it. Anyone care to point me to a direction or provide some examples?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the MVC Sample application. The setup should be identical.

Comment: I think @stephenl was referring to [the video store sample](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Msmq.Samples/blob/master/VideoStore.Msmq/VideoStore.ECommerce/Global.asax.cs)

Comment: Is NServiceBus hosting the WebApi or WebApi hosting NServiceBus? It's the second usually, but this question appears to be backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample app that walks though the various things you should know when self hosting NServiceBus https://github.com/SimonCropp/NServiceBus.SelfHost

The main code is as follows

```
class SelfHostService : ServiceBase
{
    IStartableBus bus;

    static void Main()
    {
        using (var service = new SelfHostService())
        {
            // so we can run interactive from Visual Studio or as a service
            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                service.OnStart(null);
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress any key to stop program\r\n");
                Console.Read();
                service.OnStop();
            }
            else
            {
                Run(service);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        LoggingConfig.ConfigureLogging();

        Configure.Serialization.Json();

        bus = Configure.With()
                       .DefaultBuilder()
                       .UnicastBus()
                       .CreateBus();
        bus.Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>().Install());
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (bus != null)
        {
            bus.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

It also walks you through the various sc.exe commands to install it as a service